# How to use getchar_unlocked(), I am not getting the flow in following code?

Tags: c

This code snippet is from a successfull submission of Problem name ART in CodeChef, for making it fast, coder has used `getchar_unlocked` to read integers. But I am not getting how it goes out of the loop in the following code snippet? Please can anyone help me with this? Full code can be found [here](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/10306107).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define g getchar_unlocked

int read()
{
        int n=0;
        char c=g();

        while(c<'0' || c>'9')
        {
                c=g();
        }
        while(c>='0' && c<='9')
        {
                n = (n<<3) +(n<<1) +c - '0';
                c=g();   // putting it here is giving a unusual behaviour!!!!! like not taking the input and coming out of loop ???
        }
        return n;
}
```

Comment: so where is the definition of `g()`?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't pasted full cod, but if u will open this link https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/10306107, u will get full code

Comment: What is the unusual behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* true that defining a global function named `read` (or any other name in the list at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/functions.html) could potentially cause the C library to malfunction, but I'm not sure whether this rises to the level of "undefined behavior" in the sense used by the C standard, and I can't actually make a problem happen on any operating system I can conveniently access.

So, ignoring that, here's the loop you asked about again:

```
    while (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
            n = (n<<3) + (n<<1) + c - '0';
            c = getchar_unlocked();
    }
```

And you said what you don't understand is "how it goes out of the loop".  First, [`getchar_unlocked`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar_unlocked) is just like [`getchar`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar), except that it's not thread-safe (and therefore *may* be faster).  It returns characters in sequence from standard input.  The `while` loop cycles as long as the character returned is greater than or equal to `'0'` and less than or equal to `'9'`; the C standard guarantees that the digits 0123456789 are the only characters in that range, and that they appear in the proper order.  So, if the input to the program is "1234", the loop should cycle four times and then stop, because the value returned after the 4 will be either `'\n'` or `EOF`, neither of which is in the '0'..'9' range...

```
   char c = getchar_unlocked();
```

... except that the programmer made one of the most basic mistakes when programming with stdio.  `EOF` is a value *outside the range representable by `char`*, so to store that value correctly, `c` ought to be declared as `int`.  The bug is masked by the layout of ASCII (and EBCDIC), but in a hypothetical implementation where `char` was signed, `EOF` had the value -1, and `'9' == (char)-1` -- all of these things are allowed -- the program would go into an infinite loop at EOF.

Answer (score 0):

`read` is the library function that is used to implement low level input in the C library.  Do not use this name for a function in your code, you are creating a conflict leading to undefined behavior. Rename your function.

On my system (OS/X) your program runs fine and your function reads and ignores non digits, parses a decimal number and returns it.  If you have a problem on your system, it may be related to the redefinition of `read`, which is easy to fix.

Note that you should store the return value of `getchar_unlocked()` into an `int` and compare it to `EOF` to avoid looping endlessly if no number is found before the end of file.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define g getchar_unlocked

int read_number(void) {
    int n = 0;
    int c = g();

    while (c < '0' || c > '9') {
        if (c == EOF)
            return -1;
        c = g();
    }
    while (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        n = (n << 3) + (n << 1) + c - '0';
        c = g();
    }
    // you might want to ungetc(c, stdin); to keep the first non digit
    // character in the standard input buffer for further parsing.
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    int val = read_number();
    printf("value: %d\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanku, chqrlie for this information.Next time I will keep in mind this.

Comment: But, I have given a link in my description of question , can u help me out in understanding the flow of the code in that link, plz.

Comment: Yeap, if this may be the reason of the behaviour, you should specify that, otherwise this sounds as "not an answer" (although totally deserves its spot in comments)

Comment: it is not an answer, i am thanking him because he told not to make a function name as read as its a library function.                                            I am still waiting for answer!!!!:(

Comment: This conflict actually explains the bug.  The system's read function is no longer called by `getchar_unlocked()`...